# Can I register a PuTTY key with TortoiseGit globally (not per repo)?

Tags: windows, git, putty, tortoisegit, pageant

I am familiar with using TortoiseGit + PuTTY to access a remote, you can set the PuTTY key used for a given remote via:

- the Remote node in the Settings windows
- the `.git\config` file...

```txt
[remote "upstream"]
url = git@gitlab.com:name/project.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
puttykeyfile = C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\key.ppk
```

...and get the benefits of Pageant integration and so on.

This works as expected in a local development environment. However, we are now sharing a staging repo in a shared location `\\server\share\myrepo`, so that any team member can update that repo as required. This means that we can't store the `puttykeyfile` value in `\\server\share\myrepo\.git\config`, as it is unique per team member.

Is it possible to define a "global" `puttykeyfile` in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig` or somewhere else that is user-specific rather than repo-specific?

Comment: setting `puttykeyfile` to `%USERPROFILE%\\Documents\\key.ppk` did not work (presumably environment variables are not expanded)

Comment: current workaround, define a common convention for the key location, like `C:\staging_keys\key.ppk` -- this obviously doesn't account for multiple users on the same machine, but our team shouldn't encounter that issue

Answer (score 5):

No need to edit `.git/config` by hand.
There is the `git config` command which has options like  `--system`, `--global`, and `--local`.

- "local" means "set for that repository".
- "global" means "set for all repositories of that user".
- "system" means "set fol all users of that computer".

Therefore you can set your value by something like:

```
git config --global remote.upstream.puttykeyfile C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\key.ppk
```

However (as you see above) the keyfile is configured per remote. Maybe you should give your upstream/origin remote a better name like "github" or "gitlab". Then you can specify there a key for github and one for gitlab and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

1. Instead of storing the putty key file in `repo/.git/config` it can be stored in `%HOME%\.gitconfig` by issuing `git config --global remote.upstream.puttykeyfile path\\to\\key.ppk`, where `upstream` is the name of the remote you want to use the key for.
2. You can also use PuTTY sessions in order to define a default key there (globally for "Default connection" or for specific servernames called sessions under SSH->Auth in PuTTY). See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html.
3. Or, instead of using SSH you could also switch to `https`, those credentials are stored locally.

Comment: putty sessions also mentioned on the tortoisegit mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisegit-users/V1_dKY1Hlkc